# drawing a graph in a JPanel in Net Beans

Tags: netbeans, overriding, jpanel, netbeans6.8, paintcomponent

Is there a possible way to override the paintComponent() method in the auto-generated GUI code in NetBeans? 
I managed to manually draw a graph without using the drag-and-drop components, and I need to make adjustments (e.g. adding radio button group) which I find really time consuming and tedious work. 
I created a GUI using the NetBean's drag-and-drop components, but I cannot edit them. Is it possible?

Pls give me a solution.
Greatly apprecite any insight
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can override the code used to create a component that you drag-and-drop onto a form in the NetBeans Swing UI 'builder'.

You can do the following:

1. Select a component from the palette.
2. Place the component.
3. right click on the component and select the 'Customize code' item.
4. Edit the code in the dialog that is displayed.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4c75ea4390.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4c75ea4390.png)

There is another way to customize the code, that is a bit more complex, that you may find useful.

When you drag-and-drop a component that you wish to customize, look at the Properties panel on the right-hand side of the layout editor.  You can customize code by altering the Code properties, like "Custom Creation Code".

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4809b0fd4f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4809b0fd4f.png)

There is more info about this method in this answer: [How to modify/add code to the initComponents() method in Java using NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438221/how-to-modify-add-code-to-the-initcomponents-method-in-java-on-net-beans/2439285#2439285)