# My JSpinner does not change or accept any changes that I made on it

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am working in a project where i must use a *javax.swing.JSpinner* for representing a money increment value.
I have the following problem: When I built it in my Class Constructor like the following code, the JSpinner does not change, instead it continues with the default behavior. Even I modify the enable property and nothing happens
How I can do to make the JSpinner behave as I want?

This is the code built in Netbeans:

```
public class TesingSpinner extends javax.swing.JFrame {

SpinnerNumberModel model;
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor;

/**
 * Creates new form ProbandoSpinner
 */
public TesingSpinner() {
    initComponents();
    model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.00, -1000.0, 1000.0, 0.01);
    jSpinner1 = new JSpinner(model);
    editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(jSpinner1);
    jSpinner1.setEditor(editor);
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jSpinner1.setEnabled(false);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jSpinner1.setEnabled(true);
}  

 private void initComponents() {

    jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("El Spinner");

    jButton1.setText("Bloquear");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Desbloquear");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addContainerGap(164, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TesingSpinner().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Where is `initComponents()` defined?

Comment: I omitted this code.It is what Netbeans generates.

Comment: I edited the post with the InitComponents() method

Comment: You are assigning `jSpinner1` twice, but only one of those JSpinners is added to your frame.  The one in the frame is not the one you are modifying.

Comment: @VGR is right. The `jSpinner1` field is assigned in the `initComponents` method and then again in the `TesingSpinner` constructor.

Comment: Don't create a new JSpinner in the constructor, just apply the model and editor (setModel, setEditor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the `JSpinner` definition in `initComponents()`

<strike>jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();</strike>

and change this in the constructor

```
public TesingSpinner() {
    model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.00, -1000.0, 1000.0, 0.01);
    jSpinner1 = new JSpinner(model);
    editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(jSpinner1);
    jSpinner1.setEditor(editor);
    initComponents();
}
```

Actually what is happening is that you are creating two `JSpinner`; one in the constructor and another in the `init`. After `pack()` you are controlling the second one i.e. the `init` one which is the default spinner.

---

If you can not change the code in `initComponents` you can also do this

```
    initComponents();
    model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.00, -1000.0, 1000.0, 0.01);
    jSpinner1.setModel(model);
    editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(jSpinner1);
    jSpinner1.setEditor(editor);
```

Comment: I think the code in the `initComponents` method is generated by the NetBeans GUI builder.

Comment: Yes and that's why it is messing with the logic.

Answer (score 2):

@VGR, i follow your annotations and what I did was to delete the definition in my Constructor class and code it in the initComponents() method. The behavior that i want is now happening, and the component changes it properties.

```
public TesingSpinner() {
    initComponents();
//        javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel model;
//        javax.swing.JSpinner.NumberEditor editor;
//        model = new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(0.00, -1000.0, 1000.0, 0.01);
//        jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(model);
//        editor = new javax.swing.JSpinner.NumberEditor(jSpinner1);
//        jSpinner1.setEditor(editor);
}

private void initComponents() {       
    javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel model;
    javax.swing.JSpinner.NumberEditor editor;
    model = new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(0.00, -1000.0, 1000.0, 0.01);
    jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner(model);
    editor = new javax.swing.JSpinner.NumberEditor(jSpinner1);
    jSpinner1.setEditor(editor);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans to add your own component initialization to work together with the `initComponents` method. See for example: [How to modify/add code to the initComponents() method in Java using NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438221/how-to-modify-add-code-to-the-initcomponents-method-in-java-using-netbeans)

This allows you to "Enter code as part of one of the following code properties: Pre-Creation Code, Post-Creation Code, Pre-Init Code, Post-Init Code, Post-Listener Code, Pre-Population Code, Post-Population Code and After-All-Set Code."