# how to enable read only code on netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

Working on NetBeans, sometimes when I open an existing project, some files from that project are automatically read-only. Does anyone know how it can be solved?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2439285/982161

Answer (score 0):

read-only property of a file does not depend on your Netbeans IDE. It is the attribute of the file itself. Try to remove the read-only attribute should solve your problem.

Comment: On Windows, right click on the file, select properties from the context menu, unchecked read only option and save the change. On OSX, you do something similar or use chmod command on terminal, `sudo chmod u+w filepath`.